# How to create a searchbar inside of toobar Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I've been searching for while a method of using the default searchbar on Xamarin Forms inside of Toobar, the problem is, `ToolbarItem` class doesn't have any kinda of way to integrate something different than a "Button", in android native that is possible, i've seen a lot of apps with this searchbar. I read [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ToolbarItem/) and i couldn't find anything. here what i have so far :

```
var filter = new ToolbarItem
        {
            Text = "Filtrar",
            Icon = "filter.png",
            Priority = 1,                

            Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary
        };
```

And the searchbar :

```
  <StackLayout>
<SearchBar x:Name="searchB"/>
```

Comment: Wrong approach, the only way is the platform specific way. Take an idea https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/40585/can-we-place-searchbar-in-the-navigation-bar

Comment: @GeorgePapadakis the thing is, how I could retrieve the "search result" to my Forms and do what i want?